# How can I use Ray to optimize the speed of my Python MPI code?

Tags: python, optimization, mpi, ray

Problems with using "ray" in Python.

Hi, guys. I am new to Python language.

I'm just studying about MPI in Python (Window base). My code is like this structure.

```
... ...

class A         # getting values by using interpolation 
    def a 
    def b 
    def c

for i in range(0,xxx):

    for j in range(0,yyy): 
    
      def aa(x)
        xxx = A.a(x)+A.b(x) #example
    
      def bb(x)
        xxx = A.b(x)*A.c(x) #example
    
      def cc(x)
        xxx = A.c(x)/A.a(x) #example
    
      cons = [{'type':'eq', 'fun':bb},
              {'type':'eq', 'fun':cc} 
             ]
    
      res = optimize.minimize(aa, x, bounds=( , ), constraints = cons)
    
      # writing results section (using "res")
```

I used "Ray" for my code for MPI process.

```
... ...

class A          # getting values by using interpolation 
    def a 
    def b 
    def c

for i in range(0,xxx): 
    x = initial values

    @ray.remote()                                             ## I used "Ray" here!
    def main_code(x):
        for j in range(0,yyy): 
    
          def aa(x)
            xxx = A.a(x)+A.b(x) #example
    
          def bb(x)
            xxx = A.b(x)*A.c(x) #example
    
          def cc(x)
            xxx = A.c(x)/A.a(x) #example
    
          cons = [{'type':'eq', 'fun':bb},
                  {'type':'eq', 'fun':cc} 
                 ]
            
              res = optimize.minimize(aa, x, bounds=( , ), constraints = cons)
            
              # writing results section (using "res")
    
    def main(x):                                              ## I used "Ray" here!
        return ray.get(main_code.remote(x))
    
    main(x)
```

- Goal of my code: obtaining output file with "res" values w.r.t i, j conditions.

Consequently, my code with "Ray" could not sufficiently improve operation speed. Rather, it decresed the speed !

I tried directly apply "ray" to each function - def aa, bb, cc, etc., but it was meaningless.

As my googling, I knew that I need to use "ray.wait" for pipeline process(?). BUT, I don't know how to apply "ray.wait" in my code. I couldn't find similar examples.

Could I get some comments to improve my code? I think my code is at basic level, so I need some help~!